# Create select box without current value in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a select box dynamically by jquery 
but it should not have the current value

```
    jQuery('.copyad').each(function() { ads.push(jQuery(this).attr('id'));  }); // ["ad1","ad2","ad3"]
 jQuery.each(ads , function(index, value) { 
       option += '<option value="'+value+'">Copy To Ad '+value+'</option>';
  });
jQuery('.copyad').html(option);
```

It gives the output like

```
Ad1 ===
<select class="copyad" id="ad1" >
 <option value="ad1">Copy To ad1 </option>
 <option value="ad2">Copy To ad2 </option>
 <option value="ad3">Copy To ad3 </option>
</select>

Ad2 ===
<select class="copyad" id="ad2" >
 <option value="ad1">Copy To ad1 </option>
 <option value="ad2">Copy To ad2 </option>
 <option value="ad3">Copy To ad3 </option>
</select>
Ad3 ===
<select class="copyad" id="ad3" >
 <option value="ad1">Copy To ad1 </option>
 <option value="ad2">Copy To ad2 </option>
 <option value="ad3">Copy To ad3 </option>
</select>
```

but i need the output like

```
    Ad1 ===
<select class="copyad" id="ad1" >
 <option value="ad2">Copy To Ad 2 </option>
 <option value="ad3">Copy To Ad 3 </option>
</select>

Ad2 === 
<select class="copyad" id="ad2" >
 <option value="ad1">Copy To Ad 1 </option>
 <option value="ad3">Copy To Ad 3 </option>
</select>

Ad3 === 
<select class="copyad" id="ad3" >
  <option value="ad1">Copy To Ad 1 </option>
  <option value="ad2">Copy To Ad 2 </option>
</select>
```

So on ...

How can i do this

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.copyad').each(function() { ads.push(jQuery(this).attr('id'));  });
jQuery.each(ads , function(index, value) { 
   if(ads[index] != value){
      option += '<option value="'+value+'">Copy To Ad '+ value[value.length -1] +'</option>';
   }
});
jQuery('.copyad').html(option);
```

try to add if condition like this..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to concatenate the number following the 'ad' part of the id:

```
option += '<option value="'+value+'">Copy To Ad '+ value.substr(value.length - 1) +'</option>';
```

*Edit: Based on comment below:

```
jQuery.each(ads , function(index, value) {
   if(ads[index] != value) {
      option += '<option value="'+value+'">Copy To Ad '+ value.substr(value.length - 1) +'</option>';
   }
});
```

Comment: Yes , but more i want to remove the current ad value from the select box like in Ad 1 there should be only ad 2 and ad 3 not ad1 ......